# Traffic to IP addresses matching local network not sent over VPN

Tags: network, vpn

I have an active VPN connection (L2TP) and try to access a server with IP 192.168.1.29 in the remote network.

If my local network uses the same subnetwork (192.168.1.0/24), connections to that subnet are not routed through the VPN, so the connection to the remote server fails. If my local network uses a different subnetwork (e.g., 192.168.2.0/24) the connection succeeds.

Is there a way to access my server in the first case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This is precisely why all of documentation about setting up VPN tunnels/bridges stresses the need for local and remote networks to have different subnets.

You will need to change one or the other.